# UINavigation bar appearance tint does not work in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using SwiftUI and currently setting the tint color of my navigation bar back button globally using:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
```

After upgrading to Xcode 14 and building for an iOS 16 simulator, I have noticed that the tint that I set is now being ignored and defaulting to the system blue tint color.

I have discovered that using this approach does get it to look as expected:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(image, transitionMaskImage: image)
```

However, I am curious if there are any more elegant ways of restoring the ability to control the tint globally in iOS 16

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For SwiftUI in iOS 16, to *globally* set the tint color of the **navigation bar back button**, configure the AccentColor in Assets.xcassets.
[image: Configure AccentColor in Xcode 14]

Comment: Another iOS version, another change (break?) added to the appearance API. This works, thank you Ron!

Comment: For me setting the AccentColor in Assets.xcassets did not suffice when using the new `NavigationStack` on iOS 16. I had to manually set `.tint(...)` on the `NavigationStack`. (Using the deprecated `.accentColor(...)` view modifier on the `NavigationStack`also appears to work).

Comment: But what if I want to have a different tint color _only_ for the navigation bar? So that there are two separate tints – one for the whole app (buttons, etc.) and one for the nav bar.

Comment: @alexkaessner the only solution I could find is to set the `.tint` on the `NavigationStack`, but then give its subview `.tint(Color("AnotherColor"))`. The downside of this is that you have to set it for every view in the stack.